# PropertyGrid error while operating with Database

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I am working on an application that takes data from a database into a property-grid, and normally, it should be able to edit that database.

This is a small prototype of my class:

```
public partial class MonthlyData
{
    public MonthlyData(string month, string year)
    {
        this.key = string.Format("{0} {1}", month, year);

        _IncomeMarketing = GetEntry(EntryType.Income, "Comercializarea produselor");
    }

    private string key = "";

    #region Income Properties
    [CategoryAttribute("Venituri"),
     DisplayName("Comercializare de produse"),
     Description("Venituri din comercializrea de produse")]
    public double Income_Marketing
    {
        get { return _IncomeMarketing; }
        set { _IncomeMarketing = SetEntry(EntryType.Income, "Comercializarea produselor", value); }
    }
    #endregion

    private double _IncomeMarketing;
}
```

And below is the definition of my `SetEntry()`:

```
private double SetEntry(EntryType type, string entryName, double entryNewValue)
{
    string tableName = (type == EntryType.Income) ? "Venituri" : "Cheltuieli";

    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.AccountingServicesConnectionString);
    connection.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("UPDATE {0} SET {1} = {2} WHERE Luna = \"{3}\"", tableName, entryName, entryNewValue, this.key);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // I think here is my problem!

    return entryNewValue;
}
```

In the image below are printscreens of my application in two different steps:

1. The property grid gets the correct value from the database
2. When I change that property and press ENTER, I get that error...

[image]

I don't know where is the problem. Because the database datatypes are ok (they are `double`)

Tell me anything I can offer you to help me, because I will. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
Here I can provide more information about my project. [Here](http://www1.datafilehost.com/d/bb793144) is the `.accdb` file that my project uses.

Comment: click on details and see what it has to say

Comment: it says `Unspecified error`

Comment: Enable 1st-chance exceptions in Visual Studio and debug your program. http://florianreischl.blogspot.fr/2010/01/how-to-enable-first-chance-exceptions.html

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to *catch the exception* so you can investigate it; perhaps adding some `using` at the same time:

```
try {
    using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.AccountingServicesConnectionString))
    using(var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = string.Format(
            "UPDATE {0} SET {1} = {2} WHERE Luna = \"{3}\"",
            tableName, entryName, entryNewValue, this.key);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // I think here is my problem!

        return entryNewValue;
    }
} catch(Exception ex) {
     SomeGlobalLogging(ex); // <=== put breakpoint here
     throw;
}
```

Then we can look at:

```
cmd.CommandText = string.Format(
    "UPDATE {0} SET {1} = {2} WHERE Luna = \"{3}\"",
    tableName, entryName, entryNewValue, this.key);
```

That could have any number of problems, not least: formatting issues with decimal specifiers (commas vs periods). You should use parameters, at least for the value (you can't parameterize the table / column name). IMO, {2} and {3} should become parameters:

```
cmd.CommandText = string.Format(
    "UPDATE {0} SET {1} = :newVal WHERE Luna = :key", tableName, entryName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("newVal", entryNewValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("key", this.key);
```

Comment: Yeah, the exception message is `Syntax error in UPDATE statement.`.

Comment: By copying the last code block in your answer, I still get the `Invalid UPDATE statement syntax.

Comment: @Victor right; so the next question is : what **exactly** is `cmd.CommandText` immediately before calling `ExecuteNonQuery` ?

Comment: @Victor the exact form of the required line depends on what the backend is: so - what database (etc) are you talking to here? It might need to be `@newVal` / `@key`, etc

Comment: @Victor is that Access? (shudders)

Comment: @Victor IIRC access uses positional anonymous parameters, so it would be `"update {0} set {1} = ? where Luna = ?"` - making sure to add the parameters in the existing order as stated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35259/discussion-between-victor-and-marc-gravell)

Answer (score 0):

This code block made my query work:

I had to bracket the table name, and the columns name:

string tableName = (type == EntryType.Income) ? "Venituri" : "Cheltuieli";

```
try
{
    using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.AccountingServicesConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = string.Format("UPDATE [{0}] SET [{1}] = ? WHERE [Luna] = ?", tableName, entryName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", entryNewValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", this.key);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return entryNewValue;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex); // <=== put breakpoint here
    throw;
}
```